# Curly brace behind equations

Tags: equations, positioning, environments

I have the following question: I like to have a big curly brace behind the equations to show that they belong together and have only one equation number.

An example without the brace would be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\begin{split}
    x &= r\,\cos \varphi\\
    y &= r\,\sin \varphi
\end{split}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

I would like to have the curly bracket behind the two equations. I saw this already in textbooks but have not found latex code for that. I guess it is very simple, but at the moment I have no clue how to do it. I was already searching for a while.

Comment: You're welcome! I've taken the liberty of fixing a typo in the first sentence and replacing "bracket" with "brace" in two instances, as "bracket" may be (mis)understood as a "square" bracket.

Answer (score 18):

You could use the following, modified version of the code you've provided:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\left.
\begin{aligned}
    x &= r\,\cos \varphi \quad\\ % use \quad as spacer between equation and right brace
    y &= r\,\sin \varphi
\end{aligned}
\right\}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way, both the `align` and `split` environments, which you employ in your code, let users set alignment points (e.g., the equal sign) with the `&` symbol. Using both environments simultaneously is redundant.

Note that I've substituted `equation` for `align`, and `aligned` for `split`, in the code above because you mention that you want the equations to be associated with a *single* equation number. (The `align` environment will create separate equation numbers for each equation it encounters unless you use the `\notag` command, but this seems more complicated than using the `aligned` environment inside an `equation` environment.)

Comment: Thanks @Mico for the quick answer. But what do you mean with your comment that the align environment already provides the split functionality? How do I use it? Your construction for te bracket is not working in align, at least not how I used it :)

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. What I *meant* to say is that the `align` and the `split` environments both let you set alignment points in the equation(s) -- frequently, but not necessarily so, the equal sign is chosen as the alignment point. Using both environments simultaneously is therefore redundant. If you want to retain the `align` environment, don't use the `split` environment as well. Finally, you had mentioned that you wanted a *single* equation number, so the `align` environment won't be correct in this setup as it'll create two equation numbers.

Answer (score 9):

You could use the [`empheq`](http://ctan.org/pkg/empheq) package, which provides further ways of emphasizing equations:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{empheq}
\begin{document}
\begin{empheq}[right=\empheqrbrace]{equation}
  \begin{split}
    x &= r\,\cos \varphi\\
    y &= r\,\sin \varphi
  \end{split}
\end{empheq}
\end{document}
```

[image: equations with brace]

Comment: Ah, much neater than `numcases`!

Answer (score 5):

Another approach by the [mathtools](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
    \begin{rcases}
      x = r\,\cos\varphi\\
      y = r\,\sin\varphi
    \end{rcases}
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

You may also take a look at the [cases](http://ctan.org/pkg/cases) package, which offers some more possibilities.